# After execute the rollback instruction, my table data wont go back

Tags: commit, rollback

After i type ROLLBACK; the data in the table departments_dup didnt rollback.

CREATE TABLE departments_dup
(
    dept_no CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    dept_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO departments_dup
(
    dept_no,
    dept_name
)
SELECT *
FROM
    departments;

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    departments_dup
ORDER BY dept_no;

COMMIT;

UPDATE departments_dup
SET
    dept_no = 'd011',
    dept_name = 'Quality Control';

ROLLBACK;

When i Tyep

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    departments_dup
ORDER BY dept_no;

The table still shows the wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to BEGIN or BEGIN TRANSACTION for ROLLBACK.
Your query sequence should have been,

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE departments_dup SET dept_no = 'd011', dept_name = 'Quality Control';

ROLLBACK;
```

Further reading, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_transactions.htm